# Как изменить Url или Web-Context при деплое WAR архива на WildFly

Tags: java, java-ee, веб-сервер, servlet, wildfly

Пытаюсь разобраться в работе веб-сервисов на Java.
Очень раздражает один момент. Не понимаю как настраивать url по которому нужно обращаться для работы с сервисом, когда он уже находится на WildFly.
В частности сейчас war архив деплоится по адресу: http://localhost:8080/demo-1.0-SNAPSHOT
Я хочу настроить эту часть: /demo-1.0-SNAPSHOT

Эта часть формируется из pom.xml.
Если изменить

```
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>demo</name>
```

то url тоже меняется.
Но вероятно это неправильный путь.
Подскажите пожалуйста, где это нужно настраивать. Сам найти ничего не смог.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В "pom.xml" находим тэг "build" и добавляем в него тэг "finalName".
Должно выглядеть примерно так.

```
<build>
    <finalName>${project.name}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

${project.name} будет ссылаться на тэг . Впрочем по Ctrl+B в IntelliJ Idea можно перейти к нужной переменной.

Answer (score 1):

Url, по которому будет доступно web-приложение, обычно настраивается с помощью дескриптора развёртывания специфичного для данного сервера приложений.
У Wildfly это `jboss-web.xml`, который Вы должны поместить в `WEB-INF`
И заполнить соответствующим образом

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web>
    <context-root>demo</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

Тогда url на сервере Wildfly будет `http://localhost:8080/demo`.

Коль скоро используете maven, то в исходных кодах прожекта должен быть в файл `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jboss-web.xml` с указанным выше содержимым.

Comment: К сожалению, в моём случае это не работает. Я использовал IntelliJ Idea и WildFly. Действительно на форумах я встречал такой способ, но он почему-то игнорируется. Я решил, что это уже устаревший способ так как Idea генерит класс Application с аннотацией @ApplicationPath("/api"). Спасибо, Вам!

Comment: `@ApplicationPath` - это же из JAX-RS? Он не управляет базовым адресом web-прилодения. Но определяет адрес rs сервиса внутри этого приложения:
`http://localhost:8080/demo/api` или `http://localhost:8080/demo-1.0-SNAPSHOT/api`

Comment: Да, это было моё ошибочное предположение. Из-за того, что jboss-web.xml не влиял на настройку базового адреса.